# text file: Reading file line by line

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, string, text-files

but after reading file getting output of 2nd Line is not getting with same space.why

```
THE industrial area layout                              date 11/12/2020                            
Head office                                             page no
```

below is my code

```
 lines = File.ReadAllLines(path,Encoding.UTF8));
```

text file:

```
  THE industrial area layout                              date 11/12/2020                            
  Head office                                             page no
```

After Reading:

```
  THE industrial area layout                              date 11/12/2020                            
  Head office                               page no
```

How would i be able to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the actually output you are getting? can you share that?

Comment: please can you see that? o/p

Comment: Your code is Ok, just use a mono-spaced font to diisplay this.

Comment: Maybe these are tab characters, just rendered to different widths? E.g. if you are looking at the text file in the text editor, it may render each tab as 4 spaces, but your console may render it as 8 spaces (or vice-versa).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are analyzing the content with the same font, more specifically make sure you have monospace fonts otherwise you might get confused related to the spaces.

I would suggest Courier New.

What you see in the debugger text view doesn't use a monospace font by default so it's unreliable when checking the number of spaces between lines especially when there's other content besides spaces.

Another way to check the number of spaces is to replace them with some other character so that you can count them visibly.